# Android - Repeat animation increasing duration until duration is less then a value

Tags: android, animation, rotation

i'm trying to create an animation that rotate an image inside an imageview.
That rotation must increase it velocity ( so duration ) every repeat until duration is less then a value.

What i've tried is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/my_logo"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="10"
    android:toDegrees="360">
</rotate>
```

In activity:

```
logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewToRotate);


rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.first_animation_splash);
rotation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                if(animation.getDuration()>100)
                    animation.setDuration(animation.getDuration()/2);
                else
                    logo.clearAnimation();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus){
            logo.startAnimation(rotation);
        }
    }
```

But it continue rotate with same duration 10 times.... How can i fix? Thanks!

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an especially useful description of your symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Do not have the animation automatically restart
- In `onAnimationEnd()`, change your duration and call `startAnimation()` again

My guess is that some (or all) changes to the animation object are not recognized in the middle of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to happen is that the animation ends if the duration is less than or equal to 100, then you can replace `logo.clearAnimation()` with `animation.end()`.